# Associando List<T> com WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, lista, webclient

Como associar uma classe `List` a um *WebClient*, e ao seu término chama outro *WebClient* num **index** diferente

```
List< WebClient > clients;

void BaixarTudo(List< string > urls){
  for(int i=0;i < urls.Count; i++){
     clients=new List< WebClient >(urls.Count);
  }
}
```

Mas o sistema interrompe dizendo um erro interno do aplicativo.

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você quer fazer. Explique melhor o intuito e o que é esse erro interno do aplicativo.

Comment: Fiz um teste com o código e não deu erro algum. Se faz o que você quer eu não sei porque não deu para entender o objetivo mas o código realmente não faz nada útil. https://dotnetfiddle.net/OYDNCi

Comment: tipo eu quero que ao finalizar o download do primeiro webClient automaticamente inciasse o outro download!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer (ou parece ser) não é algo tão trivial de fazer certo, e passa longe do código postado. Vou colocar um código que faz o básico praticamente montado em cima dos exemplos da documentação mas este código não está em condições de ir para produção.

```
using System.Console;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var paginas = BaixarTudo(new List<string>{"http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com"});
        foreach(var pagina in paginas) {
            WriteLine(pagina);
        }
    }
    
    public static List<string> BaixarTudo(List<string> urls) {
        var paginas = new List<string>(urls.Count);
        foreach(var url in urls) {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            using (var data = client.OpenRead(url)) {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data)) {
                    paginas.Add(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
        return paginas;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pdwNZc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetHtml.cs).

Comment: Ta até certo mas o que eu quero é baixar multiplos arquivos automaticamente!

Comment: É exatamente o que está fazendo. Se não é isto que você realmente quer, você tem que fazer suas perguntas com mais qualidade, tem que explicar o que quer com detalhes, de forma clara. O que você perguntou está respondido. O que você realmente deseja só você sabe e não foi escrito em lugar algum, portanto não tem como ninguém adivinhar o que seria, só podemos responder em cima do que está escrito de fato.